# change value of json key in N1QL couchbase

Tags: couchdb, sql++

I want to change **"UpdatedFromIP" to "IP"** in N1QL using update query ??

I want to do it for all json. where _type="log"

```
 {
  "UpdatedFromIP": "1.0.0.166",
  "_type": "log",
    "updatedBy": 529
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the field name, which you can do with a combination of a SET clause (to add the new field name) and an UNSET clause (to remove the old field name) in the UPDATE statement. If your bucket were named 'default', the following query should work:

```
update default set IP = UpdatedFromIP unset UpdatedFromIP 
where _type = "log" and UpdatedFromIP is not missing;
```